# Load webbrowser content into another webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net

I have such situation:
1) One form named 'frm_iexplorer' with webbrowser and loaded document into it.
2) One class named 'PrintHTMLDocument' which creates webbrowser dynamically.
I would like to load a same document into second, dynamically created webbrowser from first webrowser.

My approach in class is like:

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Navigate(frm_iexplorer.WebBrowser1.document())
```

... don't work.
frm_iexplorer is not accessible.

How to do this?

Comment: The webbrowser is meant to navigate. If you want to get a given page, you have to navigate to get it. You can get the associated document, store its contents in a (string) variable and do anything you want with it, but don't think that you can do the same with a WebBrowser control (what would be point?). Can you please, explain your exact requirements and why you have to rely on two webBrowsers?

Comment: PS: bear in mind that you can also "navigate" through your hard-drive (and thus might store a copy of the given page), although I am not sure that doing all this would be faster than just going to the site again.

Comment: Hi varocarbas, Here is real need to do that. Loaded document in first webbrowser is editable and can be changed. Second webbrowser have to print document from first webbrowser as it is so document from first have to be loaded in second webbrowser. I still belive that here is some direct way to do that without (say) saving/loading to/from file.

Comment: What you have to understand is that the purpose of a webBrowser is (web)browsing. To accomplish this aim, there are some "side functionalities", like displaying the given page; but all this is secondary and depends upon the main browsing feature. If what you want is just displaying something, rely on a control to display things. If what you want to display is a webpage, this is not something static (like a picture), but dynamic, which has to be loaded dynamically (after "browsing" it). I don't see the problem to navigate twice (neither an alternative... other than the local-file loading).

Comment: Note that ".document" does not contain the information you want to see; but just the html. This html has to be translated (+ put the images and the dynamic content together), doing all this is precisely (part of) browsing. If you want to get the pure text (html), it is easy: store it in a string variable.

Comment: That may be good (transfer a string), But how will I get this string when program is in class? How would I get html string (content) from first webbrowser when I need to "navigate" in class if frm_iexplorer is not accessible (blue underlined) in class?

Comment: No, perhaps I didn't make myself clear: you have to navigate to get a new document in a webBrowser (you can navigate through internet or your hard-driver where you have stored the document from the previous webBrowser), but you can not set the document variable directly, this is the point I am intending to make since the start. What I said is that if you want to store pure text (= without navigating = without bringing the webBrowswer into picture at all), you can get the html from the document. Dynamic behaviour  (= proper page)+ setting webBrowser props implies navigating (to an address).

Comment: OK, then problem would be a new one. In first webbrowser I have loaded local HTML document created with VB which contain textboxes (editable). Now I think that it would be enough to save changed document to disk (same one to which WB is navigated) say under webbrowser_lostfocus handler so second webbrowser can load that, changed document. Then, now is question how to save changed document to (same name) file?

Comment: Document is a string (no matter how big and how many html tags has in it), as string you can modify it as much as you want and store it to a file ("fileTemp.html") by doing, for example: System.IO.File.WriteAllText("fileTemp.hml", modifiedDoc). Then you can go with the second browser and open this file.

Comment: Hm, here are huge problems with saving a document. I will need to make a new topic about this tomorrow. Thank you varocarbas for trying to help.